# How to combine Plot, Manipulate and ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to combine "`Plot`, `Manipulate` and `ContourPlot`", into one graphics display.

I tried `Show[plot1, plot2, ...]` but it didn't work.

```
f[x_] := 1 - (x - 4)^2
g[x_] := 0.6 x + 1

plot1 =
  Manipulate[
    Plot[{n f[x] + g[x], f[x], g[x]}, {x, 2, 6}, 
      PlotRange -> 8, AspectRatio -> 1], 
    {n, 1, 5.5}]

plot2 = 
  ContourPlot[{x == 3, x == 5}, {x, 2, 6}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    Frame -> False, Axes -> True]

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: Use Show inside Manipulate. Also use `With` to inject `ContourPlot` so it won't be recalculated each time.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're just using `ContourPlot[]` for the vertical lines, I would suggest using the `GridLines` option instead:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{n f[x] + g[x], f[x], g[x]}, {x, 2, 6},
                AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
                GridLines -> {{{3, ColorData[97, 1]}, {5, ColorData[97, 2]}}, None},
                GridLinesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
                PlotRange -> {-4.1, 9.1}],
           {{n, 3.25}, 1, 5.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

or if you have version 10, the new `InfiniteLine[]` primitive:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{n f[x] + g[x], f[x], g[x]}, {x, 2, 6},
                AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
                Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
                           {{ColorData[97, 1], InfiniteLine[{3, 0}, {0, 1}]},
                            {ColorData[97, 2], InfiniteLine[{5, 0}, {0, 1}]}}},
                Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-4.1, 9.1}],
           {{n, 3.25}, 1, 5.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the `Show` inside of the `Manipulate`

```
f[x_] := 1 - (x - 4)^2
g[x_] := 0.6 x + 1

plot2 = ContourPlot[{x == 3, x == 5},
   {x, 2, 6}, {y, -5, 9.1}];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[{n f[x] + g[x], f[x], g[x]},
   {x, 2, 6},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotRange -> {-4.1, 9.1},
   AspectRatio -> 1],
  plot2],
 {{n, 3.25}, 1, 5.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]